# $\int_a^{b} f(x) dx$ exists then so does $\int_{a+c}^{b+c} f(x-c)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am with a friend doing some late night math at math club and we came across this problem:

$f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and let $c \in \mathbb R$. I am trying to show that

$\int_a^{b}  f(x) dx$ exists then so does $\int_{a+c}^{b+c} f(x-c)dx$ and these two integrals are equal.

This seems almost trivial to us as we quickly computed some integrals and this was obvious, however we are having some trouble proving this. Is there some rule where you can subtract a constant in the integral and add it in the integral bounds. I have never used this before. Help would be great! Just want to understand how this is actually proved. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, the lower bound of the second integral should probably be $a+c$.

Comment: Yes typed it wrong thank you fixed it in edit

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is continuous, one can use substitution.  Letting $u=x+c$ be a function of $x$, then we have the corresponding differentials $du=dx$, and so $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=\int_{u(a)}^{u(b)}f(u-c)\,du=\int_{a+c}^{b+c}f(u-c)\,du$.

However, $f$ is only specified to be a function, and that the integral exists.  For this, we may use the Riemann integral $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{b-a}{n}f(a+\frac{b-a}{n}i)$, and by some algebra get $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(b+c)-(a+c)}{n}f(a+c+\frac{(b+c)-(a+c)}{n}i - c)=\int_{a+c}^{b+c}f(x-c)\,dx$.

Comment: would this suffice to a proof though?

Comment: Could I simply just state use a substitution then subtract the 2 integrals from each other and get 0 so then they are equal

Comment: Yes, that sounds sound to me.

Comment: You don't even need to subtract them.  The substitution gives equality (assuming you can use that theorem).  Wikipedia shows how to do it directly from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution

Comment: This requires that $f$ be continuous, which is typically the case, but not necessary for a proof.

Comment: @copper.hat you are correct. This not only requires continuity, but continuous differentiability.

Comment: Continuity of $f$ is sufficient, you need $C^1$ for the limit functions, but that is not relevant here...

Comment: @copper.hat again, you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

It is straightforward to prove from the definition.

Let $f'(x) = f(x-c)$.

Suppose $P=(a=x_0,x_1,...,x_{n-1},x_n = b)$ is a partition of $[a,b]$ and let
$P' = (x_0+c,x_1+c,...,x_{n-1}+c,x_n+c)$ (which is a partition of $[a+c,b+c]$).

Then $U(f,P) = U(f',P')$ and $L(f,P) = L(f',P')$.

Similarly, if $P'$ is a partition of $[a+c,b+c]$, we can construct an corresponding partition of $[a,b]$.

It follows that $\inf_P U(f,P) = \inf_{P'} U(f',P')$, and similarly $\sup_P L(f,P) = \sup_{P'} L(f',P')$. Hence $f'$ is integrable and the integrals are the same.

Comment: Do you mean "and similarly for the upper sums."

Comment: Well, the $U$s are the 'upper sums' and the $L$s are the lower sums. I edited the answer to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: ahh makes sense thank you

Comment: I am doing this problem and am wondering why $U(f,P) = U(f',P')$ @copper.hat

Comment: @mathguy84: Just write out the expressions for both and it will be clear. Expand $f'$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\int_a^b f(x) \ dx,$
Let $t = x + c$, we immediately learn a few things:

1. $f(t - c) = f(x)$
2. $dx = dt$
3. $x=a\implies t = a + c$
4. $x = b\implies t = b + c$

It follows from substitution that 
$$\int_a^b f(x) \ dx = \int_{a+c}^{b+c}f(t-c)\ dt$$

Further, since these are both definite integrals, the use of $t$ and $x$ is interchangeable. So we have
$$\int_a^b f(x) \ dx = \int_{a+c}^{b+c}f(x-c)\ dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Sketch the graphs of $y=f(x)$ and $y=f(x-c)$ over the intervals $(a,b)$ and $(a+c, b+c)$, respectively. You will find they are identical except for a horizontal translation. The integrals represent the (net) areas under these curves over the respective intervals, which will of course be the same.

Comment: He realizes this. He is trying to figure out how to prove it symbolically.