# Prove that $\int_a^{b} f(x) dx$=$\int_{a-c}^{b-c} f(x+c)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want to prove that if f is continuous, it is verified that

$\int_a^{b} f(x) dx$=$\int_{a-c}^{b-c} f(x+c)dx$

My attempt was as follows

Considering that f is continuous let us substitute such that $t=x-c$ with $dx=dt$

It is clear that $f(t+c)=f(x)$. If $x=c$ then it must follow that $t=a-c$ and if $x=b$ it must follow that $t=b-x$

It follows that:
$\int_a^{b} f(x) dx$=$\int_{t(a)}^{t(b)} f(t+c)dt$

And by substituting

$\int_a^{b} f(x) dx$=$\int_{a-c}^{b-c} f(x+c)dx$

What I did was to use the rule of integration by substitution (if I am not wrong); I know very well how is the proof using partitions, however I want to know if this demonstration is also valid.

Comment: What is the proof with partitions?'

Comment: If you consider the Lebesgue Integral, then you can use the fact that the Lebesgue measure is invariant under translations.

Comment: I agree that this statement has a trivial proof using partitions, but what's the point of looking for a proof using "less elementary" tools? These rules of substitution in integrals ultimately rely on properties of partitions and supremums, so this does not really provide a different viewpoint, as I understand.

Comment: I agree with @Gollum. Even if it's easy, the intended proof definitely involves partitions.

Comment: That's right, it involves partitions; however I saw a demonstration similar to the one I present in Apostol's Calculus. My doubt is, is that demonstration also valid?

Comment: I just don't know what you really proved. You basically just applied substitution. In my opinion, the only useful exercise for this type of problem is proving substitution in full generality using partitions

Comment: I understand; but I have a question, why in this exercise do they do a similar prove?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247690/int-ab-fx-dx-exists-then-so-does-int-acbc-fx-cdx

Comment: Hint: $\int_{a - c}^{b - c}{f(x + c)dx} = F(b - c + c) - F(a - c + c)$

Comment: The substitution rule is usually established using a fundamental theorem of calculus; whether or not the stated proof is "valid" or "unjustified" depends on the available tools.

Comment: You do not need continuous. Integrable is good enough